# Rails app in EC2 is not reachable but Python is

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to deploy a rails app to a EC2 instance, if I made a basic index in html an run it with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 3001` I can see the html file in my browser and responds to a `wget` from my local computer, unfortunately if I made a basic rails app with:

```
rails new testApp
bundle install
rails s -p 3001
```

I'm unable to reach it from my browser, the server console don't show any sign of getting the request, if I made a wget request from the EC2 instance `wget localhost:3001` it works fine, but if I do it from my local machine I don´t get response.

The python server works, so I know that is not my EC2 machine configuration, the default rails app works with Puma and it works if I run one in my local machine, is there something else that I have to do in order to access my rails app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rails server` binds to localhost in the development environment by default.  You can configure it with the `-b` switch.  Per `rails server --help`:

> -b, [--binding=IP] # Binds Rails to the specified IP - defaults to 'localhost' in development and '0.0.0.0' in other environments'.

`rails s -p 3001 -b '0.0.0.0'` should work.